# Magento2 to_html_after event was remove?

Tags: magento2

How can I get intercept html output in magento2?

For example, for magento 1.x i can do:

```
///core_block_abstract_to_html_after
$block = $observer->getBlock();
if($block->getNameInLayout() == 'root'){
    $output = $observer->getTransport()->getHtml();
}
```

In magento2 the to_html_after event was remote?:
[https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/0.42.0-beta10/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php#L622][1]

Comment: Looks like `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` has been replaced by `core_layout_render_element`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use plugins/interceptors.
For Magento 1 it wasn't even a good practice to use the event `core_block_abstract_to_html_after`. That one got dispatched for all blocks and observing it would create an overhead.
With plugins/interceptors you can get your hands on the html for a specific block.
You can read [this documentation](https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/Using+Interception)
Just to explain in a few words...

you need to add this in the `di.xml` of your module

```
<type name="NameOfClass\You\Intercept\Here">
    <plugin name="some-unique-name-here" type="Your\Class\Name\Here" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

`NameOfClass\You\Intercept\Here` is the name of the core block you want to get your hands on.
`Your\Class\Name\Here` is the class your create in order do your changes.
It's similar to the observer in Magento 1.

```
<?php 
namespace Your\Class\Name;
class Here 
{
    //'after' is reserved word. 
    //`ToHtml` is the name of the method your want to intercept, capitalized
    //in this case you want to intercept the toHtml method of a certain block
    //the first parameter is always the name of the class you intercept with the reserved word `Inteceptor` at the end. This will give you access at the class instance
    //the second parameter is what the original toHtml method returns. This is the html you want
    public function afterToHtml(
         \NameOfClass\You\Intercept\Here\Interceptor $original,
         $html
    ) {
        //do something with $html
        //make sure you return a value of the same type as the original method
        return $html;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marius. The only question: in magento 1.xx I find block by block name in layout, now should i use block classname directly? I know, that the plugin will work with child objects, but what will happen if the class will be replaced?

Comment: @sergei.sss. Good question. I'm afraid I'm not that advanced to answer it.